# Is $\left(1-\dfrac1n\right)^{a_n}$ increasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Let $a_n=\left\lfloor\sqrt{2n-2}\right\rfloor+1$. Prove that this holds for $n\in\Bbb N$.

> $$\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{a_n}\le\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{a_{n+1}}$$

My try:

> If $n=1$ then $a_n=a_1=\left(1-\frac11\right)^{a_1}=0$ and
> $a_{n+1}=a_2=\left(1-\frac12\right)^{a_2}$, which is $1/2$ or $1/4$,
> depending on $a_2$. So the statement is true for $n=1$.
>
> Let $n$ the least natural number that does not hold the inequality. [This is a subtle way to use induction on $n$].
>
> Using the sum of geometric progressions, we obtain: $$\sum_{k=0}^{a_n} \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^k=\frac{1-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{a_n+1}}{1-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)}=n\left[1-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{a_n+1} \right]$$
> therefore,
> $$1-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{a_n+1}=\frac1n \sum_{k=0}^{a_n} \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^k$$
> And similarly,
> $$1-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^{a_{n+1}+1}=\frac1{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^{a_{n+1}} \left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^k$$
> Since $n$ does
> not hold the statement,
> $$\frac1{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^{a_{n+1}} \left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^k>\frac1n \sum_{k=0}^{a_n}  \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^k$$

But I dont know how to go on. I'd like a proof like this. No limits, continuity or mention to number $e$.

Perhaps the statement hols only for large enough $n$. If it holds for $n\ge 100$, this would work for me, too.

Comment: You will save yourself a lot of work if you try to compute the first few values to check if it holds before trying to prove it. Here it fails already at $n=5$.

Comment: Seems to fail without limit for all positive integers in the sequence generated by $\left\lfloor 1/2 (1 + (k + 2)^2) \right\rfloor$, with k integer.

Comment: Re the comment of @Winther, I have found it helpful for this and other problems to be able to programmatically sanity check, rather than manual eval's.  So, you might consider the preliminary step of becoming moderately fluent in something like Python, C or Java.

Comment: Yes I completely agree with that, doing it quickly in Python is very useful and much faster. Such numerical experiments will also very often give you some insight into things that you *can* try to prove. For example here it will reveal (as noted above by James) that the failures happen when the sequence has jumps $a_{n+1} - a_n = 1$. One can then try to see what happens with the inequality at a jump. Some algebra on the inequality gives us that if its to be satisfied then we need $a_n \sim n$ so the sequence has to be "pretty close" to $a_n = n$ for this to hold.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the logarithm to both sides of
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{a_n}\le\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{a_{n+1}} \tag{1}$$

you get
$$\frac{\lfloor\sqrt{2n-2}\rfloor+1}{\lfloor\sqrt{2n}\rfloor+1}\overset{?}{{>}} \frac{\ln\Big(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\Big)}{\ln\Big(1-\frac{1}{n} \Big)}\tag{2}$$

Note that since $(1-\frac{1}{k})$ is less than one,  $\ln(1-\frac{1}{k})$ is negative therefore the direction of the inequality has been changed.

We will have that $\lfloor\sqrt{2n-2}\rfloor$ is not equal $\lfloor\sqrt{2n}\rfloor$ only when $2n$ is a perfect square:
$$\begin{matrix}
\lfloor\sqrt{2n-2}\rfloor=k-1 & \text{when } 2n =k^2 \\
\lfloor\sqrt{2n-2}\rfloor=\lfloor\sqrt{2n}\rfloor & \text{otherwise}
\end{matrix}$$

therefore we will have
$$1\overset{?}{{>}} \frac{\ln\Big(1-\frac{1}{x+1}\Big)}{\ln\Big(1-\frac{1}{x} \Big)}\tag{a}$$
$$\frac{k}{k+1}\overset{?}{{>}} \frac{\ln\Big(1-\frac{2}{k^2+2}\Big)}{\ln\Big(1-\frac{2}{k^2} \Big)}\tag{b}$$

The relation $(a)$ holds for every real $n$ and therefore also for every integer $n$ since the argument of the logarithm to the denominator is greater than the argument of the logarithm to the numerator. While $(b)$ didn't holds for any real $k$. So whenever $2n$ is a perfect square $(1)$ it is false

$$\left(1-\frac{2}{k^2}\right)^{k}>\left(1-\frac{2}{k^2+2}\right)^{k+1} \Rightarrow \left(1-\frac{2}{2n}\right)^{\lfloor\sqrt{2n-2}\rfloor+1}>\left(1-\frac{2}{2n+2}\right)^{\lfloor\sqrt{2n}\rfloor+1}$$